# when saving the images in LRUCache, then what is the strategy to get images back on orientation change

Tags: android

I am using LRUCache to download images from server and showing on my activity views. I am not saving these images permanent storage(e.g. SD Card).
My Problem is that as my orientation changes, my LRUCache's object is destroyed and i am not able to get the images back after orientation change.

Before using the LRUCache i was storing the images in bundle, and hence, using onSaveInstanceState(bundle) it was easy to deal with that problem. But how to do like this with LRUCache object. Help!

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is to use a Fragment for that page.  Then you can do `setRetainInstance(true);` to keep the OS from destroying the fragment on a config change.

Another way is to put the LruCache in an Application derived class.  This is one way to keep persistent data between Activities too.

Answer (score 1):

In onSaveInstanceState, try using `LruCache.snapshot()` to get a Map of your cache entries, ordered from least to most recently used. You could then write each key,value into the Bundle. Then when restoring from the Bundle, iterate each entry and `put()` them back into the LruCache.

Comment: Man! thanks.. But i will be more convenient if you could give me some lines of code demonstrating this.:)

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate Class which contain a static variable holding your LRU class, your LRU will not be destroyed because it is a separate reference.

```
class MyLRU { 

     public static LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache = new .....

}
```

To call the cache from your activity:

```
   Bitmap myImage =  MyLRU.mMemoryCache.get("imagekey");
```